# jquery to hide and show div using dropdown

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

I am using below code to show/hide divs based on dropdown choice. The code works perfectly until I start using iframes to call local pages on my server.

What then seems to happen when I test it by choosing different options in the dropdown, is that the first time you choose the 6 options it works fine but when you keep testing it over and over and refresh the page, the last 3 options show the content for the first 3 options. ie. When I choose box 4, it shows the iframe for option 1. When I choose box 5, it shows the iframe for option 2. When I choose box 6, it shows the iframe for option 3. The first 3 options work fine - just not 4,5 and 6. This only seems to happen in IE. Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#box1').hide();
    $('#box2').hide();
    $('#box3').hide();
    $('#box4').hide();
    $('#box5').hide();
    $('#box6').hide();
    $("#thechoices").change(function(){
        if(this.value == 'all') {
            $("#boxes").children().show();
        } else {
            $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();}
    });

    $("#thechoices").change();
});
</script>
<body>
    <select id="thechoices">
        <option value="box1">Box 1</option>
        <option value="box2">Box 2</option>
        <option value="box3">Box 3</option>
        <option value="box4">Box 4</option>
        <option value="box5">Box 5</option>
        <option value="box6">Box 6</option>
    </select>

    <!-- the DIVs -->
    <div id="boxes">
        <div id="box1">1
            <iframe src="iframe1.php?currency=gbp" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="box2">2
            <iframe src="iframe1.php?currency=us" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="box3">3
            <iframe src="iframe1.php?currency=euro" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="box4">4
            <iframe src="iframe1.php?currency=au" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="box5">5
            <iframe src="iframe1.php?currency=nz" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div id="box6">6
            <iframe src="iframe1.php?currency=ca" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are using an outdated jquery version; use the last stable version: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js or (if you don't need IE8 and below) http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js

Comment: Just a tip: to hide multiple elements you can use a multiple selector, such as `$('#box1, #box2, #box3...').hide();`. In this case you can also use an [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) such as: `$('div[id^=box]').hide();`

Comment: It only seems to happen if I refresh the page after choosing a select option

Answer (score 0):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/9F2RP/)

### Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#thechoices").change(function(){
        $('#boxes div').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

### CSS

```
#boxes div
{
    display:none;
}
```

Hope this helps,Thank you